# How to convert mouse cursor to loading in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, mouse, matlab-guide

How can i convert mouse cursor from `normal` to `loading` in `MATLAB` and return it to `normal icon` after some codes in a `GUI` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at `set(figure_handle,'Pointer',...);`?

Comment: I found this link based on your function : http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-mouse-pointer-functions . please add your answer with more information. Thanks.

Comment: I would let you do it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use these codes:

```
set(figure_handle,'Pointer','watch');

%% some codes 

set(figure_handle,'Pointer','arrow');
```

Thank you @Divakar for your comment.